# OpenGL GLI errors when compiling

Tags: c++, opengl, compiler-errors, include

When I'm try to compile with gli/gli.hpp I've got the errors follow. I've never touched those files before. So I don't know how to fix the problem.

```
In file included from /usr/include/gli/gli.hpp:42:0,
              from window.cpp:4:
/usr/include/gli/./core/storage.hpp:89:25: error: declaration of ‘gli::storage::format_type gli::storage::format() const’ [-fpermissive]
/usr/include/gli/./core/format.hpp:36:8: error: changes meaning of ‘format’ from ‘enum gli::format’ [-fpermissive]

In file included from /usr/include/gli/gli.hpp:45:0,
              from window.cpp:4:
/usr/include/gli/./core/texture2d.hpp:71:24: error: declaration of ‘gli::texture2D::format_type gli::texture2D::format() const’ [-fpermissive]
/usr/include/gli/./core/format.hpp:36:8: error: changes meaning of ‘format’ from ‘enum gli::format’ [-fpermissive]

In file included from /usr/include/gli/gli.hpp:46:0
             from window.cpp:4:
/usr/include/gli/./core/texture2d_array.hpp:72:24: error: declaration of ‘gli::texture2DArray::format_type gli::texture2DArray::format() const’ [-fpermissive]
/usr/include/gli/./core/format.hpp:36:8: error: changes meaning of ‘format’ from ‘enum gli::format’ [-fpermissive]

In file included from /usr/include/gli/gli.hpp:47:0,
             from window.cpp:4:
/usr/include/gli/./core/texture3d.hpp:71:24: error: declaration of ‘gli::texture3D::format_type gli::texture3D::format() const’ [-fpermissive]
/usr/include/gli/./core/format.hpp:36:8: error: changes meaning of ‘format’ from ‘enum gli::format’ [-fpermissive]

In file included from /usr/include/gli/gli.hpp:51:0,
             from window.cpp:4:
/usr/include/gli/./core/load_dds.hpp:37:3: error: ‘string’ is not a member of ‘std’

In file included from /usr/include/gli/./core/load_dds.hpp:41:0,
             from /usr/include/gli/gli.hpp:51,
             from window.cpp:4:
/usr/include/gli/./core/load_dds.inl: In function ‘gli::storage gli::loadStorageDDS(const string&)’:
/usr/include/gli/./core/load_dds.inl:303:1: error: ‘gli::storage gli::loadStorageDDS(const string&)’ redeclared as different kind of symbol
/usr/include/gli/./core/load_dds.hpp:36:10: error: previous declaration of ‘gli::storage gli::loadStorageDDS’
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're not telling your compiler that you need to compile using the C++11 standard.

If you're using gcc then you must pass

```
-std=c++11
```

on your command line (or -std=c++0x if you're using an older version of gcc)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is appears that your C++ compiler is more strict than the one used to develop gli.  Going through the errors, the first can be silenced (not necessarily fixed properly) by adding `-fpermissive` on your `g++` line.  This error looks like it comes from using the wrong return type on `gli::storage::format()`

```
In file included from /usr/include/gli/gli.hpp:42:0,
              from window.cpp:4:
/usr/include/gli/./core/storage.hpp:89:25: error: declaration of ‘gli::storage::format_type gli::storage::format() const’ [-fpermissive]
/usr/include/gli/./core/format.hpp:36:8: error: changes meaning of ‘format’ from ‘enum gli::format’ [-fpermissive]

In file included from /usr/include/gli/gli.hpp:45:0,
              from window.cpp:4:
/usr/include/gli/./core/texture2d.hpp:71:24: error: declaration of ‘gli::texture2D::format_type gli::texture2D::format() const’ [-fpermissive]
/usr/include/gli/./core/format.hpp:36:8: error: changes meaning of ‘format’ from ‘enum gli::format’ [-fpermissive]

In file included from /usr/include/gli/gli.hpp:46:0
             from window.cpp:4:
/usr/include/gli/./core/texture2d_array.hpp:72:24: error: declaration of ‘gli::texture2DArray::format_type gli::texture2DArray::format() const’ [-fpermissive]
/usr/include/gli/./core/format.hpp:36:8: error: changes meaning of ‘format’ from ‘enum gli::format’ [-fpermissive]

In file included from /usr/include/gli/gli.hpp:47:0,
             from window.cpp:4:
/usr/include/gli/./core/texture3d.hpp:71:24: error: declaration of ‘gli::texture3D::format_type gli::texture3D::format() const’ [-fpermissive]
/usr/include/gli/./core/format.hpp:36:8: error: changes meaning of ‘format’ from ‘enum gli::format’ [-fpermissive]
```

The following error appears to be a case of the wrong header file being included.  In particular, `load_dds.hpp` includes another header file (`storage.hpp`), which includes `<cstring>`, and not `<string>`, which is where C++ declares `std::string`.  Quick fix is to add `<string>` into `storage.hpp` in your downloaded copy, and file a bug.

```
In file included from /usr/include/gli/gli.hpp:51:0,
             from window.cpp:4:
/usr/include/gli/./core/load_dds.hpp:37:3: error: ‘string’ is not a member of ‘std’
```

For this one, I believe the issue is that in `load_dds.hpp`, `gli::loadStorageDDS` is delcared as a function, but not labeled as being `inline`, where that's what is going on in `load_dds.inl`.  The `.inl` mechanism appears to be something of a Microsoft concoction, and so you may need modify the `.hpp` to include `.inl` implementations to keep things consistent. (That's a guess, BTW).

```
In file included from /usr/include/gli/./core/load_dds.hpp:41:0,
             from /usr/include/gli/gli.hpp:51,
             from window.cpp:4:
/usr/include/gli/./core/load_dds.inl: In function ‘gli::storage gli::loadStorageDDS(const string&)’:
/usr/include/gli/./core/load_dds.inl:303:1: error: ‘gli::storage gli::loadStorageDDS(const string&)’ redeclared as different kind of symbol
/usr/include/gli/./core/load_dds.hpp:36:10: error: previous declaration of ‘gli::storage gli::loadStorageDDS’
```